# UITextField not type a word from keyboard in IOS

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I am using UITextField. but I am not able to type any word from keyboard. I have tried to set text for textfield. I can delete the text, but not able to add or edit character. 
The application works okay for the first time. But, only the first,
I have tried to research but I wasn't able to find anything helpful.
I am newbie, please help me.
Thanks

Comment: Please elaborate a bit more on what your problem is.

Comment: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-fvFxZCiXv4Y/UVmiVQcv7LI/AAAAAAAAB-U/tJ9J_OTpoPw/s480/iOS+Simulator+Screen+shot+Apr+1%2C+2013+5.31.32+PM.png

Please watch image link. I have UITextField, I can't type text from keyboard

Answer (score 0):

You have provided insufficient data. Please post questions with more clarity.
You can append/add text in the textfield by the following;

```
textField.text = [textField.text stringByAppendingString:@"stringYouWantToAdd"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your Textfield to enabled state

```
[textfield setEnabled:YES];
```